# Off-topic posts being used to link to from outside

Tags: discussion

A poster has written [something long-ish which was voted as off-topic/personal theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/745328).  I don’t have any issue with that.  However, they state in comments that they intend to leave it closed and undeleted so that they can give the link to other people.

> I am happy if people leave this without deleting it. It has given me excellent formatting, and **a simple link I can give out**. People can contact me personally, so they will not flood StackExchange [sic] with responses.

The bold highlighting is mine.

I wonder if this is appropriate as the site exists to explain mainstream physics, not to help promote personal theories.

Should this post (and any similar ones in the future) be deleted so that Physics SE is not connected to personal theories or used as a repository for them?  My view would be to delete this, but that raises the question if *all* personal theory-type questions should be deleted for consistency.  That seems a bit drastic and leaves us with considering on a case by case basis.

Some community guidance would be useful here.

Note it was suggested by another user that the post might be auto-deleted anyway by the system.  Can anyone confirm that this is they case or not?  If so, it would make my concerns about linking to it irrelevant.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Posting something that is not an on-topic question merely to use our site as storage for it is a misuse of the site and should not be tolerated.

Since this specific question is closed, downvoted and without answers, it would not have stayed undeleted for long anyway due to the [roomba](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) (see the link for the specific criteria for auto-deletion), but I have hastened its deletion manually.

It is perfectly fine to vote to delete such posts (remember that users with >20k reputation can vote to delete any post) or to raise custom moderator flags if you think any particular off-topic post needs to be deleted faster than the usual roomba logic would delete it.